How can I match ID# from my date dataframe to match with the date's in my main dataframe?
dfDates = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": ['2023-06-20 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-21 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-22 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-23 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-24 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-25 09:00:00-07:00', ], 
        "entryId": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ],
    })

dfTrades = pd.DataFrame(
{
        "Date": ['2023-06-20 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-24 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-22 09:00:00-07:00' ], 
        "symbol": ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'MSFT' ],
})
dfDesired = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "Date": ['2023-06-20 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-24 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-22 09:00:00-07:00' ], 
    "symbol": ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'MSFT' ],
    "entryId": [1,5,3 ],
})


I have two data sets.  One named dfDates and another table named dfTrades.  My goal is to combine the entryId's from dfDates onto dfTrades.  I'm pretty sure the best solution is to use merge() or maybe join()?  But not to sure how to properly accommplish this.

A simple merge will do: dfTrades.merge(dfDates.rename(columns={"date": "Date"})) or dfTrades.merge(dfDates, left_on="Date", right_on="date")

Or you can use series.map if you want to add the column to dfTrades: dfTrades['entryId'] = dfTrades['Date'].map(dfDates.set_index('date')['entryId']).

One way is to merge() and then drop() date:
import pandas as pd

dfDates = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": ['2023-06-20 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-21 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-22 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-23 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-24 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-25 09:00:00-07:00', ],
        "entryId": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ],
    })

dfTrades = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ['2023-06-20 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-24 09:00:00-07:00', '2023-06-22 09:00:00-07:00'],
        "symbol": ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'MSFT'],
    })


dfDesired = pd.merge(dfTrades, dfDates, left_on='Date', right_on='date', how='left')
dfDesired.drop(columns=['date'], inplace=True)

print(dfDesired)


Prints
                        Date symbol  entryId
0  2023-06-20 09:00:00-07:00   AAPL        1
1  2023-06-24 09:00:00-07:00   TSLA        5
2  2023-06-22 09:00:00-07:00   MSFT        3

